# Weird output of python array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm newbie in python. I don't understand the output of following python program.

```
arr = []
for i in range(3):
    arr.append(i * 2)
for arr[i] in arr:
    print arr[i]
```

Output:

```
0
2
2 // Why also print 2??
```

Here, An array elements print twice time `2`. This is really weird. 
Please someone help me to clear my doubt. Why program print twice time `2`?

Comment: because you're using the `arr[i]` - i.e. - `arr[2]` as the loop variable! You want to do `for x in arr: print(x)`

Comment: What happens if you change the second loop to `for j in arr: print j`? Not sure what you're trying to achieve by having arr[i] as the iterating value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your second loop is using the array itself as the loop variable, overwriting the last value. It should have been written like this:

```
for x in arr:
    print x
```

PS. Since you're just starting in Python: Switch to Python 3 today!

Comment: python 3 also, print same output.

Comment: That's right. There is no difference between Python 2 and 3 with respect to your question, but you should switch because of several important things that do differ.

Comment: @rsp  I would suggest to keep a keen eye on "both" versions of Python (they aren't different languages!).  There is a lot of code in Python 2, and there will be yet more, for a long while.  But it may well be a good idea to focus on 3, unless you have an immediate need for 2.

Answer (score 2):

What `for arr[i] in arr:` does is that it reassigns the first and then second element of `arr` to `arr[i]` which at that point is `arr[2]`. That is why your first and second elements of `arr` are unchanged but the last one has the value of the second.

A for loop in Python loops through elements of an iterable, i.e. your loop will literally fetch element by element like @Alexis explained. In this case it means it will return each element of `arr` and assign it to `arr[i]`. It will do that for the last element too - leaving it unchanged but already equal to the second element of `arr`.